# Lack of obviousness about how to use this site

Tags: feature-request, status-deferred, new-users, help-center

The problem is hardly unique to this SE site, but for people new to the site there is fundamental knowledge that isn't obvious.

For instance, the "tour" page doesn't mention that questions must be set up so that they can be scored, independent of votes, nor does it provide a list of "scoring tags".

Similarly searching for "score" on the help page produces nothing useful.

That seems like a very important concept for this site, so why isn't it presented front and center?

One specific improvement would be if the question submission form required one of the scoring tags, the same as meta sites require one of a set of tags.

Comment: In short, Stack Exchange is built as a Q&A platform and we have basically no control over how things are presented.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this up here. Unfortunately, there isn't much we can do. We've added things to the tour page, the info box, and meta to do as much as we're able to, but unfortunately our site isn't a good fit for SE and we get issues like this. I've closed this off as a duplicate of another post to point people there since it includes some more details about what we can and have done.

Answer (score 6):

The Tour and Help Center only have [very specific items/pages that can be customized](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259920/295232). Besides that, not everybody reads them.

The points you mention *are* highlighted in the right sidebars of

1. All question list pages, including the home page:

   [image]
2. The Ask Question wizard:

   [image]